# Get color union possibilities to generate another color

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, algebra

I have a set of colors in RGB hexadecimal.  I need to calculate the **combination of colors** to get a specified hexadecimal color.

Eg:

```
Input hex - #3A5F34

Output: 

1 - 20% #FF0000 + 80% #00AA33
2 - 30% #FFAA00 + 40% #0A33BB + 30% #FFFFFF
3 - ...
...
```

For instance, if I have only red, black and yellow, is it possible to generate another color (specified) from combinations of that set. The objective is show union possibilities to create a input color.

I made much search and did not find salient discussions for that problem.

In my ideas, this circled in universe of HEX - RGB conversion and union probability but, my tests don't give satisfactory results. Some imagination possibilities:

*- Brute algorithm of unions calculation based on array of main colors (primary, secondary, etc)*

*- Artificial Intelligence to make a evolutive population of color unions?*

Any ideas to make that solution (or light to that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a linear combination problem in 3 dimensions.  You have a basis set of vectors.  In your given example, these are

```
b1 = (FF, 00, 00)
b2 = (00, AA, 33)
b3 = (FF, FF, FF)
```

You are trying to find a linear combination of these three vectors to give you the vector `(3A, 5F, 34)`.
Convert the vectors to integers and apply standard methods for solving systems of linear equations:

```
b1   = (255,   0,   0)
b2   = (  0, 176,  51)
b3   = (255, 255, 255)
need = ( 58,  95,  52)
```

You now need to find coefficients x (for b1), y (b2), z (b3) such that

```
need = x*b1 + y*b2 + z*b3
```

Expanded, this is:

```
255x +   0y + 255z = 58
  0x + 176y + 255z = 95
  0x +  51y + 255z = 52
```

You have three equations in three variables.
Can you take it from here?  Both Python and Java have linear solving packages to do the arithmetic for you -- no need for artificial intelligence.

---

**Get percentages**

The needed proportions are `x, y, z`.  Note that these are *not* percentages: there is no guarantee that the given mixture comes out as coefficients that add to 1.  Consider a simple case: full-intensity green `00FF00` and blue `0000FF`, but we want something in the teal range `00C0C0`.  The resulting mixture is (0.0, 0.75, 0.75) -- not percentages.

---

**Determine multiple solutions**

This is a linear system, giving us three possible cases:

1. Inconsistent: two of the equations are parallel planes, and there are no possible solutions.
2. Point solution: the equations describe three planes, intersecting in a point.  There is exactly one algebraic solution.  It is possible that one or more of the coefficients is negative, which means that there is no *practical* solution.
3. Multiple solutions: the equations intersect in a common line ... or all three equations describe the *same* plane.  In either of these cases, solving the system results in a parameterized equation in one (line) or two (plane) variables.  In either of these cases, there are infinite solutions.

Whatever tool you choose (or write) to solve the system of equations should return a parameterized form for case 3.

Comment: Thanks dear Prune! I liked your explanation but, some questions arise from that, for example:

- How to I get another possibilities of combinations? (10 another, for example)
- And the percentage of each color into combination? (10% of X and 90% of Y)

Comment: Thank you so much for the attention and the perfect explanation! That provide for me a new vision to resolve that problem in programmation. Again, thanks!